# Why does Typescript NOT need typescript-runtime, the way traceur needs traceur-runtime?

Tags: typescript, traceur

Both Typescript and Traceur compile ES6 down to ES5 right, so what's the need for traceur-runtime? Secondly, why's there no typescript-runtime?

PS: I read that traceur-runtime *shims the "missing" functions, and also does more than that and provides helper functions that are used by some features*, but i'm not sure what that really means

Answer (score 3):

> Secondly, why's there no typescript-runtime

It assumes that the user will add the stuff they need themselves e.g. if you are using promises it assumes that *your runtime has it*.

For other stuff like class inheritance it provides helpers *inline* e.g. :

```
class Base{ }
class Child extends Base { }
```

generates (notice `__extends`):

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Base = (function () {
    function Base() {
    }
    return Base;
})();
var Child = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Child, _super);
    function Child() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return Child;
})(Base);
```